# Iterate all XML nodes and their childs

Tags: dom, vbscript, xml-parsing

What would be the most efficient way in VBScript to iterate through an XML file.

I am looking for **a way to iterate all nodes in the XML file**. I cannot use XQL queries, because I really do need to iterate all nodes to check all attributes in the file.

*PS: Basically I am writing a script to replace references to file paths. The problem is that these file paths can be in a big number of places. (But that's for me to find out). I only need help with the XML iterating part.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I suspect that putting some intelligence and XPath expressions into the search would increase effiency, this

```
Option Explicit

Dim oXDoc  : Set oXDoc = CreateObject( "Msxml2.DOMDocument" )
oXDoc.async = False
oXDoc.load "..\data\31677574.xml"

If 0 = oXDoc.ParseError Then
   WScript.Echo oXDoc.documentElement.xml
   walk oXDoc.documentElement, 0
Else
   WScript.Echo oXDoc.ParseError.Reason
End If

Sub walk(e, i)
  WScript.Echo Space(i), e.tagName
  Dim a
  For Each a In e.Attributes
      WScript.Echo Space(i + 1), a.name, a.value
  Next
  Dim c
  For Each c In e.childNodes
      walk c, i + 2
  Next
End Sub
```

output:

```
cscript 31694559.vbs
<Configuration>
        <Add SourcePath="\\sample" ApplicationEdition="32">
                <Product ID="SampleProductID">
                        <Language ID="en-us"/>
                        <Language ID="en-us"/>
                </Product>
        </Add>
</Configuration>
 Configuration
   Add
    SourcePath \\sample
    ApplicationEdition 32
     Product
      ID SampleProductID
       Language
        ID en-us
       Language
        ID en-us
```

will visit all elements and their attributes.

Comment: The `Dim x : Set x = ` syntax is neat. Never seen it on one line.